# Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'sendUs'

Tags: angular

I'm trying to work with an Angular Material package for entering and validating international telephone numbers which is ngx-mat-intl-tel-input and in order to do that, i had to work with the form group but i'm having the following error :

```
Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'sendUs'
```

Here is my code html :

```
  <div class="bo4 of-hidden size15 m-b-20">
     <form [formGroup]="'sendusForm'">
          <input type="text" formControlName="phone">
      </form>
  </div>
```

and here is my typescript file :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
      sendusForm: FormGroup;
      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder)   {
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.sendusForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          phone: ['',  [Validators.required]]
        });
      }

      get f() { return this.sendusForm.controls; }
    }
```

Please can you help me solve this probleme.

Comment: `[formGroup]="'sendusForm'"` -> `[formGroup]="sendusForm"`

Answer (score 0):

check this [working example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xkdrynnqdmd)

```
<div class="bo4 of-hidden size15 m-b-20">
     <form [formGroup]='sendusForm'>
          <input type="text" formControlName="phone">
      </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
[formGroup]="'sendusForm'"
```

to

```
[formGroup]="sendusForm"
```